# Can we Convert location SQL to C# LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, geolocation, webapi

This is a SQL statement that returns a list of users that are within a 30 mile radius

```
SELECT
    id, (
      3959 * acos (
      cos ( radians(78.3232) )
      * cos( radians( lat ) )
      * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(65.3234) )
      + sin ( radians(78.3232) )
      * sin( radians( lat ) )
    )
) AS distance
FROM users
HAVING distance < 30
ORDER BY distance
```

I am using a C# .NET Web API2, is it possible to convert the above to a LINQ statement so we can have an API fetch this data?

Comment: nothing stopping you using dapper and using your sql directly

Comment: _LINQPad_ might

Comment: This query does not compile: the `HAVING` should be `WHERE`, or there should be `GROUP BY id, lat, lng`. Moreover, unless `distance` is present in the table, it would need an `APPLY` or a derived table

Comment: You can use entity framework behind your api. Then you can just use linq to represent that sql statement. There's bunch of tutorials on how to add entity framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to define this method for radians

```
    public static double Radians(double angle)
    {
        return (Math.PI / 180) * angle;
    }
```

now, you can use this query

```
        var distances = users
            .Where(x => x.YourFilterOnPagination)
            .ToList() // your collection most be List 
            .Select(x => new
            {
                id = x.id,
                distance = (395 * Math.Acos(Math.Cos(Radians(78.3232)) *
                            Math.Cos(Radians(x.lat)) * Math.Cos(Radians(x.lat) - Radians(65.3234)) +
                            Math.Sin(Radians(78.3232)) *
                            Math.Sin(Radians(x.lat))))
            })
            .Where(d => d.distance < 30)
            .OrderBy(d => d.distance);
```

> YourFilterOnPagination: If your data is big you can limits it in w

Comment: worked like a charm, I believe the first x.lat should be x.long, after i made that change it worked like a charm! Thank you again!